How do I filter a dataframe for participants who've successfully responded to a survey at least 3-4 times in R?
probably a silly question coming from a rookie here. I have a dataframe acquired via an app called SEMA3. Essentially participants are prompted once every 3 days to complete a small survey for about a month (total 10 repeated measures) that I will use rmcorr (a repeated measures correlation package) to analyse.
The problem is we have an enormous attrition rate and many participants will complete between 1-2 surveys before quitting. This is an administration issue outside the scope of my project so I am interested in analysing data from subjects who have at least responded to 3 or 4 surveys.
Currently, my code looks like:
data <- data %>%
    mutate(across(c("TODAY_TINNITUS_INTENSE","TODAY_VISUALSNOW_INTENSE"),
                  ~na_if(., "<no-response>")))

participant_sorted <- data %>%
    group_by(PARTICIPANT_ID) %>%
    drop_na(TODAY_VISUALSNOW_INTENSE, TODAY_TINNITUS_INTENSE) %>%
    filter()

I'm struggling to think of any conditions that will work in the filter function so I'm wondering if I should iterate over the data and count, for each subject, the number of responses to the variable in question. Is this viable or is there an easier way I haven't yet considered?
Thank you for all your help :)

As the name suggests, drop_na() will already remove the cases that are NA for either of those 2 variables. drop_na() is really just a convenience function for filter(is.na(x.)). So just remove the last step, and you should be down the cases you want. Also, you don't need to group_by() for the filtering process - likely not a big deal, but it will slow down the code execution.

Build a summary frame with subject ids and number of completed  surveys, filter it by your set threshold (3 or 4), use remaining subject ids to filter your survey data. For something less generic please consider editing your question and include a small example dataset in some reproducible form that would work with your included code snippet. In this case it's probably easier to craft some toy dataset instead going for a sample from your actual data.  https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Here are two cases. The first has one row for each valid survey. The second has one row for every possible survey, but NA's where missing.
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(PARTICIPANT_ID = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  TIN = "some response")

df2 <- data.frame(PARTICIPANT_ID = rep(1:4, each = 4)) |>
  mutate(TIN = if_else(row_number() <= PARTICIPANT_ID, 
                       "some response", NA), .by= PARTICIPANT_ID)
  

In the first case we could filter where n() >= 3. But that wouldn't work in the second case; there, we could sum up the number of non-NA's per participant and confirm they're >= 3.
df1 |>
  filter(n() >= 3, .by = PARTICIPANT_ID)

df2 |>
  filter(sum(!is.na(TIN)) >= 3, .by = PARTICIPANT_ID)

